# Find n'th derivative of polynomial and smallest possible degree

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, elementary-functions

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree strictly less than 100 and such that it does not have $x^3−x$ as a factor.If

$\frac{d^{100}}{d x^{100}} \frac{p(x)}{x^3-x} =\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

for some polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ then find the smallest possible degree of $f(x)$

Comment: Do you want to exclude constant polynomials? I believe if $p(x)$ is constant, this question is trivial (I have not worked it out, so I could be wrong...)

Comment: @Clayton Yes. I guess we have to exclude constant polynomials

Answer (score 0):

Using the division algorithm we have
$$
\frac{p(x)}{x^3 − x}= q(x) +\frac{r(x)}{x^3 − x}$$

As the degree of $q(x)$ is strictly less than that of $p(x)$ its $100-$th derivative is certainly zero. As $x^3 − x$ is not a factor of $p(x)$ one may assume (without loss of generality) that $x^2 − 1$ divides $r(x)$. In that case we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm d^{100}}{\mathrm dx^{100}}\frac{p(x)}{x^3 − x}=
\frac{\mathrm d^{100}}{\mathrm dx^{100}}\frac{k}{x}=\frac{100!k}{x^{100}}
$$

Hence the least possible degree of $f(x)$ is $0$.
If one assumes that $x^3 − x$ doesn't divide $p(x)$ then we have
$$\frac{r(x)}{x^3 − x}=\frac{A'}{x}+\frac{B'}{x-1}+\frac{C'}{x+1}$$

Consequently,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}&=\frac{A}{x^{101}}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^{101}}+\frac{C}{(x+1)^{101}}
\end{align}
$$
and then
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=A(x^2-1)^{101}+{B}{(x^2+x)^{101}}+{C}{(x^2-x)^{101}}\\
&=(A+B+C)x^{202}+101(B-C)x^{201}+\left[\binom{101}{2}B+\binom{101}{2}C-101A\right]x^{200}+\cdots
\end{align}
$$
Choosing $B = C$ and $A+B+C = 0$ we see that the coefficient of $x^{200}$ is $101\cdot 102 \ne0$. Hence the least possible degree of $f(x)$ in this case is $200$.

Comment: Hi, @alexjo. I don't understand the reasoning behind "one may assume that $x^2+1$ divides $r(x)$"

Comment: $\deg(r(x))<\deg(x^3-x)^3$. So we have $\deg r(x)\le 2$, and we can choose $r(x)=k\cdot (x^2-1)$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining :)

Comment: @alexjo how did you write $\frac{d^{100}}{d x^{100}} \frac{p(x)}{x^3-x} =\frac{d^{100}}{d x^{100}}\frac{k}{x}$ and why did you choose $B=C$ and $A+B+C=0$?

Comment: Also can you explain how did you expand $A(x^2-1)^{101}+B(x^2+x)^{101}+C(x^2-x){101}$?

Comment: $\deg q(x)<\deg p(x)$ and then $q^{(100)}(x)=0$. We want the smallest degree, so when $A+B+C=0$ the $x^{202}$ won't be present and when $B=C$ the $x^{201}$ won't be present; the coefficient of $x^{200}$ won't be zero and then $x^{200}$ will be present. $A(x^2-1)^{101}+B(x^2+x)^{101}+C(x^2-x)^{101}$ can be expanded using the binomial theorem and taking only the highest powers, because we are interested to  find the smallest possible degree of $f(x)$.

Comment: @alexjo I got point about $q(x)$ but I didn't get how did you write $r(x)/x^3-x$ as $k/x$